# linear regression: comparing R2 in the full model to R2 under k-fold cross-validation

Tags: r, linear-regression, cross-validation, r-caret, k-fold

Below is R code that does the following:
1. Generates data for linear regression (4 predictors, multivariate normal data, based on a correlation matrix)
2. Runs 10-fold cross-validation using caret, providing summary R2 results
*3. Correlates the predicted values across all the folds with the actual values, then squares it to get the cross-validated R2 -- this is the variable 'ar2' in the code below.

*So my question is #3 above: Why doesn't caret just compute this? Instead, it reports an R2 within each fold, explains variability in R2 across folds, etc. But if I want to know overall out-of sample prediction, based on cross-fold, it seems like #3 above is more direct.

```
# cross-validated linear regression
library(MASS)
library(caret)

# first generate random normal data
sigma <- matrix(c( 1,  .35, .20, .10, .25, 
                  .35, 1  , .15, .30, .30,
                  .20, .15,  1 , .40, .20,
                  .10, .30, .40, 1  , .35,
                  .25, .30, .20, .35,   1), ncol=5)

d <- mvrnorm(n = 100, rep(0, 5), sigma)

# label variables here
colnames(d) <- c(paste0("x", 1:4),"y")
# look at top of data set
head(d)

# generate means and correlations
apply(d,2,mean)
cor(d)
d <- as.data.frame(d)

# what if we used the whole sample, no cross-validation?
full <- lm(y ~ ., data = d)
summary(full)

# now let's look at cross-validated prediction

data_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, savePredictions="all")     # folds for cross-validation
model_caret <- train(y ~ .,   # model to fit - the dot means include all x's
                     data = d,                        
                     trControl = data_ctrl,              # include the folds above
                     method = "lm")                      # specify linear regression                
model_caret           # results from cross-validation
# look at predictions for each fold
model_caret$resample
# summarized results
model_caret$results
# all data put into final model
summary(model_caret) 

# what is the r2 between observed and predicted values?
# get the predicted values across folds
a <- model_caret$pred
# correlate actual and predicted values
ar2 <- cor(a[,1],a[,2])^2
ar2

# ...we can compare this r2 (ar2) from cross-validation to the r2 from the full model
# and get a direct sense of how r2 goes down under cross validation...right?
```

Comment: The R^2 for each fold more or less tells you how much the R^2 can vary when shown different subset of the data. And this is the purpose of cross-validation, you want to find the best hyper-parameter (there's none for lm) and you use the average metric (R^2 or RMSE) across all folds to know which is the best

Comment: If by "overall out-of sample prediction", you mean the average R^2 is subsampling,then what you are doing might be a bit off. The residual sums will differ for each fold, and lumping all of them together in one calculation like you did for #3, is ignoring the effects of subsampling. You should take the average across all R^2 given by caret

Comment: thanks for your time - so the predicted values here come from each subsample/fold being submitted to its respective training model - so I'm not clear how subsampling is being ignored, but I'm sure* I'm missing something here (not you!) - thanks again

Comment: Since you are building k models to evaluate model performance it makes sense to have k R^2 which will report the performance. Like this you not only get the idea of the expected performance but also its data dependent variance. That being said using all of the out of fold predictions to generate one metric is not that uncommon. For instance [mlr package offers this type of aggregation](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/aggregations.html) - test.join - the reasoning for the aggregation   is mentioned on the linked page.